# if always false with equal variables

Tags: shell-script

I first get file size info with curl

```
fileSize=$( curl http://linux.die.net/include/sys/ioctl.h --head | grep Content-Length | awk '{print $2}')
```

`echo $fileSize` is 1825

then I download the file and check the size

```
downloadedSize=$(wc -c ioctl.h | awk '{print $1}')
```

`echo $downloadedSize` is 1825

then I want to compare these variables. but condition always false

```
if [[ "$fileSize" == "$downloadedSize" ]]; then
    echo "success"
  else
    echo "fail"
  fi
```

I tried these

```
if [ "$fileSize" == "$downloadedSize" ]; then
if [ $fileSize == $downloadedSize ]; then
if [[ $fileSize == $downloadedSize ]]; then
```

and `-eq` instead of `==`

What is wrong ?

Comment: you want `wc -c <filename`.

Comment: same thing happen. if condition is always false

Comment: lose `awk`, too

Comment: try `-eq` instead of `==`  : `if [[ $fileSize -eq $downloadedSize ]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running :

```
$ echo "$fileSize" | od -c
0000000   1   8   2   5  \r  \n
0000006
$ echo "$downloadedSize" | od -c
0000000   1   8   2   5  \n
0000005
```

shows you in the first case there is a carriage return appended to the value (http-headers have dos line terminations: CRLF) while the second variable is correct. Strip the CR (`\r`) and your test will work. e.g.:

```
fileSize=$( curl http://linux.die.net/include/sys/ioctl.h --head |
   awk '/Content-Length/ {gsub("\r",""); print $2; exit}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both the operands in the condition are numeric, you should use

```
if [[ $fileSize -eq $downloadedSize ]]; then
```

If there are any spaces in the variable value, the case will take care of that.

Comment: I got error : `")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[` or `[[`, syntax is not same. Those are not same command. Possible to make solution using builtin commands, not huge external awk. I use grep, same is possible to do using builtin `case` command.

```
filesize=$(curl http://linux.die.net/include/sys/ioctl.h --head | grep Content-Length)
downloadedSize=$(wc -c < ioctl.h )
filesize=${filesize//[^0-9]/}              # rm not numbers 

downloadedSize=${downloadedSize//[^0-9]/} 

answer="not same"
# compare strings
[ "$filesize" = "$downloadedSize" ] && answer="same"
echo "$answer"
```